# Have cloned Python Flask application and deployed on Heroku. But its displaying ' Internal Server Error '

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, git-clone

Cloned a previous Python Flask app and deployed on Heroku but its displaying 'Internal Server Error' and when checked logs it says

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused 
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Are you sure that the PostgreSQL database connection credentials are correct?

Comment: Yes, they are correct.

Comment: Have you tried testing with the wrong password to see if you get different error message? Next stage is to ensure server is listening e.g. for me it's the cmd (windows) `netstat -ant | findstr 5432`

Comment: A snippet of the code that configures the connection would be helpful, too. If you are using Heroku's `DATABASE_URL` variable to get the connection string, remember that you may get a non-standard port, so you'll need to make sure all options (host, port, database) are read.

Comment: @AndrewAllen when looked up for that port...there are 3 processes running

Comment: App is working on local. But why Heroku is unable to detect that server is already running.

Comment: Working now with heroku db..... Config variable was incorrect